# How to expand EXT4 volume in a centos KVM guest after resizing the guest's LV

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm

I have a fedora KVM host with all the centos VMs in their own LVs.  I'd like to expand an EXT4 home volume on a guest that resides on a LV called "thelogicalvolume" in volume group "thevolumegroup"...

On the host I have run:

```
# sudo lvextend -L +1T thevolumegroup/thelogicalvolume
```

which results with:

```
Size of logical volume thevolumegroup/thelogicalvolume changed from 500.00 GiB (128000 extents) to <1.49 TiB (390144 extents).
Logical volume thevolumegroup/thelogicalvolume successfully resized.
```

Then...

In the guest i tried:

```
# sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-home
```

Which results in:

```
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
The filesystem is already 116684800 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

```
# df
```

on the VM returns:

```
Filesystem              1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  52403200   1316820  51086380   3% /
devtmpfs                  1928348         0   1928348   0% /dev
tmpfs                     1940276         0   1940276   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     1940276      8764   1931512   1% /run
tmpfs                     1940276         0   1940276   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                 1038336    192804    845532  19% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home 459282608 435929264         0 100% /home
tmpfs                      388056         0    388056   0% /run/user/1000
```

I can't see the free space from within the VM using fdisk, parted, etc.

On the host I also tried:

```
sudo virsh blockresize --path /dev/thevolumegroup/thelogicalvolume --size 1T <domain>
```

No luck.

I have searched for solutions, but have not found one that works with this setup, or I am overlooking something.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is it `/dev/thevolumegroup/thelogicalvolume` = `/dev/mapper/centos-home`

Comment: Hi Romeo, I updated my question with more info about the volume.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: What is the result of `vgs`? It seems for me like you extend wrong volume

Comment: Ugh, sorry.  My edits were formatted incorrectly.  This site is new to me.  I hope I have cleared up the issue.  VGS on the host:  ` VG               #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree `
  `thevolumegroup   1  12   0 wz--n- <5.00t <1.81t`

Answer (score 0):

```
# sudo virsh qemu-monitor-command <domain> info block --hmp
```

returns:

```
drive-virtio-disk0 (#block181): /dev/mapper/thevolumegroup-thelogicalvolume (raw)
    Attached to:      /machine/peripheral/virtio-disk0/virtio-backend
    Cache mode:       writeback, direct
```

then

```
# sudo virsh qemu-monitor-command <domain> block_resize drive-virtio-disk0 1500G --hmp
```

The size is the total desired size including the new space.  In this case 1500G (500G + 1000G).
The extra space now appears on the guest in fdisk.